# Webdriver flash button

Tags: java, flash, testing, selenium, webdriver

I have a flash button in my page:

`<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/stc/uploader.swf" width="150" height="28" id="publishComponentFlash" style="visibility: visible; "><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></object>`

I'm trying to use Webdriver (function click()) in this button but it's not working.

`WebElement btnSearch = driver.findElement(By.id("publishComponentFlash"));
btnSearch.click();`

someone help-me?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Is there any kind of error message? Could you please show it here? Are you sure you [waited](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for the element to show up?

Comment: The answer below solve my doubt. Selenium does not work with flash. Neither error message is displayed, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium Web Driver does not support/work with Flash.